# Fill Combo on change Trigger using JQuery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, onchange, jquery-trigger

I have two `DropDowns`, on `change` event of one Drop Down, i haved filled the 2nd Drop Down.
when i trigger the change event of first drop down on `Arrow Keys`, its not working, while on `Mouse click` its working fine.
Here is my Code..

```
$('#cmbCategory').on('change', function () {
    //alert($(this).val());
    // the below function will get Sub Categories from DataBase.
    getSubCategories($('#cmbCategory :selected').val(), '');
}).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 37 || e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 39 || e.keyCode == 40) {
        $(this).trigger('change');
    }
});
```

This code works fine while using `Mouse`, but doesn't work on `Arrow Keys`.
Any Help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to add `keyup` event or you can also use `keypress` event

```
$("#cmbCategory").keyup(function(e) 
{
        if (e.keyCode == 40) 
        {  
            getSubCategories($('#cmbCategory :selected').val(), '');
        }
        if(e.keyCode==38)
        {
            getSubCategories($('#cmbCategory :selected').val(), '');
        }

});
```

Note: Above code is not tested